# Mahalanobis distance between 2 line features

Tags: ekf, mapping

I am implementing the **ATLAS SLAM** framework for a ground robot, using EKF Slam for local maps and using line segment features. The line segment features can be abstracted to their respective lines `[d,α]` where `d` and `α` represent the distance and angle in the distance-angle representation of lines.

In the given framework, there is a local map matching step where lines of the local maps will be matched, and there is a need for a distance metric between 2 lines. The mahalanobis distance is suggested in the literature, however strictly a mahalanobis distance is between a single measurement and a distribution and not between 2 distributions.

How do I find the mahalanobis distance between line 1 `[d1,α1]` with covariance matrix `S1` and line 2 `[d2,α2]` with covariance matrix `S2`?

In the **EKF Algorithm** from the book Probabilistic Robotics by Sebastian Thrun, there is a computation during the feature update step, where it looks like the covariances (of a new measurement and an existing measurement) are multiplied to give a resultant covariance matrix, and then the inverse is used in the Mahalanobis distance computation.

That would be similar to

```
Mahalanobis_Distance = [d2-d1,α2-α1] * Inverse(S1*S2) * [d2-d1,α2-α1]'
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to measure the statistical difference between two distributions. For your case, you might consider the [Bhattacharyya distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance). From that page, the Bhattacharyya distance $D_B$ is

$$
D_B={1\over 8}(\boldsymbol\mu_1-\boldsymbol\mu_2)^T \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\boldsymbol\mu_1-\boldsymbol\mu_2)+{1\over 2}\ln \,\left({\det \boldsymbol\Sigma \over \sqrt{\det \boldsymbol\Sigma_1 \, \det \boldsymbol\Sigma_2} }\right),
$$

where $\boldsymbol\mu_i$ and $\boldsymbol\Sigma_i$ are the means and covariances of the distributions, and

$$
\boldsymbol\Sigma={\boldsymbol\Sigma_1+\boldsymbol\Sigma_2 \over 2}.
$$

I would also like to issue a warning. When calculating the difference between angles (e.g., $\alpha_1 - \alpha_2$ in your case), you have to take care of wrapping issues. For example, for $\alpha_1 = -179$ deg and $\alpha_2 = 179$ deg, their different is not $(-179) - (179) = -358$ deg, but rather it is $2$ deg. If you are only concerned about the relative values of statistical differences (e.g., "which is the smallest"), then consider using the *circular distance* ($c$) between the two angles, which is

$$
c = \frac{1 - \cos(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)}{2}.
$$

This always returns a value $c\in[0,1]$, where $c=1$ is the result when the two angles 180 degrees apart. So if you use the Bhattacharyya distance, the angle part of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ would be a circular distance. However, if you are looking at lines, rotating a line 180 degrees returns it to its original orientation! That's because the directions of lines are examples of *axial data*, and are invariant to rotations of +/- 180 degrees. In this case, just double the angle of the above circular distance; i.e.,

$$
c = \frac{1 - \cos[2(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)]}{2}.
$$

Now $c=1$ when the lines are 90 degrees apart!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Mahalanobis distance is useful because it is a measure of the "probablistic nearness" of two points.

For example, if I have a gaussian PDF with mean zero and variance 100, it is quite likely to generate a sample around the value 100. ($(100-0)/100 = 1$).  However, a gaussian PDF with mean 100 and variance 1 is *more likely* to be the PDF which generates samples around 100. ($(100-100)/1=0$). So we consider the point "closer to" the second one.

Thus, we need a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) to determine which PDF was a "better" choice when determining who generated the sample 100.

So in your case, it depends on which quantities were being generated by random processes.  For example, if you assumed that $d$ and $a$ were being measured, but corrupted by independent random noise, then yes, your definition of the Mahalanobis Distance is correct.

It is very unlikely that the noise on $d$ and $a$ are independent, since they probably aren't being measured independently. However, many algorithms make such an assumption. Make sure yours does.

Answer (score 0):

This is might not be an answer but check out this book [Robotic Navigation and Mapping with Radar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BEZNHGY)  page 126.  They discuss  the Mahalanobis distance better than what stated in Probabilistic Robotics. Also, they mention why this method also known as the Nearest Neighbor (NN) is not a good solution in some situations and they state another solutions.